# Subdomain redirection to directory on another domain

Tags: domains, redirects

I was wondering what is going to be the easiest way to do the following;

Point wibble.site1.com to site2.com/directory/

So that wibble.site1.com/index.php will read from site2.com/directory/index.php

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, pretty much everything I have found online helps you jump around within your own domain or gets you to the root of another domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to wibble.site1.com and if its server is Apache, you could a `.htaccess` with this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wibble\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/directory/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It should work.